# Passing the event from the class to the object

Tags: javascript, class

I'm using http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree
I don't understand how to bubble an event up into an object.

I have my class

```
class FTree2 {

    constructor(xparent) {
        this.xparent = xparent;
    }

    Init(params) {

        this.objtree = $(this.xparent).fancytree({
            extensions: ["dnd", "filter"],

            activate: function(event, data) {
                alert("activate");
            }
        });
    }

    addNode(title) {
        var tree = $.ui.fancytree.getTree(this.xparent);
        var parent = tree.getRootNode();

        var node = parent.addChildren({
            title: title,
            folder: false,
        });
    }
}
```

I use it this way:

```
  var ftree = new FTree2("#tree");
  ftree.Init();

  ftree.addNode("first");
  ftree.addNode("second");


  MyFunction() {
      alert ("node activated");
  }
```

How can I "connect" MyFunction to fancytree function "activate"?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass it as an argument:

```
    Init(callback) {

        this.objtree = $(this.xparent).fancytree({
            extensions: ["dnd", "filter"],

            activate: function(event, data) {
                callback()
            }
        });
    }
```

```
function MyFunction() {
  alert ("node activated");
}

var ftree = new FTree2("#tree");
ftree.Init(MyFunction);

ftree.addNode("first");
ftree.addNode("second");
```

Comment: may as well pass `event` and `data` to the callback?

Comment: Yes, you can do that